# Comparing date with other column and replace with text and delete rows in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have to compare date in the column with the current date and Add 3months to current date(means two dates current date and future date) and replace(`<=180 days` with `<=90 days`) the text in the another column if the future date is greater than the date in column, if the future date is less than the date in column has to delete the entire row and the macro also have to check the text in the another column(text as `Expired`) if the current date is greater than the date in the column.

Let me explain the entire code what it does.

1. I have copied the entire worksheet(`sheet1`) of basic data to the master workbook(application)
2. From the column A in the attached pictures I have filtered the unique values and placed at different column(AZ). Based on these unique value, during the execution of macro it will create a diferent workbooks. For example: APE.xlsx, SAD.xlsx, base.xlsx and so on...

   3. I have assigned these uniques values to array
   4. I have another two filter criterias in the same worksheet(`sheet1`) but with based on one filter criteria, the data has to push to another worksheet(`Aging`) and with another filter criteria it must populate data to another worksheet(`Aging 3m`) of same workbook(APE.xlsx)
   5. In the same manner I have done to the another worksheet(`sheet2`). I have compared the arrays in `sheet1` and `sheet2`, if both are equal creates a workbook with the array name.

what I want is:

1. can I use same range filter twice in a `For ...loop`?
2. The filter criteria is different but has to create push the date for two different sheets(`Aging, Aging 3mEx`) using the same
   worksheet(`sheet1`) of same workbook.
3. For the sheet(`Aging 3m`) I have to compare date column(`E`) with another column(`G`) in the attached pictures, compare date with
   current date and future date.
   a. If future date is greater than date
   in column `E` then replace '<=90 days' to '<=180 days'
   b. if future
   date is less than date in column `E` then delete the entire row.

Note: sArray has uniques values (`APE`,`APE_A`,`APE_D`,`APE_S`,`APE_U`,`APE_R`,`APE_O`,`APE_F`,`XXUMA`)  and saArra has (`APE`,`APE_A`,`APE_D`,`APE_S`,`APE_U`,`APE_R`,`APE_O`,`APE_F`)

My code:

```
Sub vba()
   Dim sArray as string
   Dim saArray as string
   Dim m as integer                
   Dim rngFilter_Ws2 as range
   Dim rngCopyAging_Sub as range                
   Dim Array_Sub_Aging as variant
   Dim Array_Sub As Variant                
   Dim NewBook_Sub as workbook
   Dim p as integer
   Dim Lastrow_Sub as integer
   Dim Lastrow_Sub_Aging as integer                
   Dim Future_date as date
   Dim current_date as date                
   Dim Ws2_Lrow As Long
   Dim Ws2_Lcol As Long                    

 current_date = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
Future_date = Format(DateAdd("m", 3, current_date), "dd.mm.yyyy")

 Ws2_Lrow = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
 Ws2_Lcol = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
Set rngFilter_Ws2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Ws2_Lrow, Ws2_Lcol))

workbook.worksheet("sheet1").Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,                    CopyToRange:=.Range("AZ1"), Unique:=True
Lastrow_Sub_Aging = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp).row
Array_Sub = Range("AZ2:AZ" & Lastrow_Sub)

workbook.worksheet("sheet2").Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,                    CopyToRange:=.Range("AZ1"), Unique:=True
Lastrow_Sub_Aging = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp).row                            
 Array_Sub_Aging = Range("AZ2:AZ" & Lastrow_Sub)

   For m = LBound(Array_Sub_Aging) To UBound(Array_Sub_Aging)

     saArray = Array_Sub_Aging(m, 1)
     Set NewBook_Sub = Workbooks.Add

        If sArray = saArray Then 'And sArray <> saArray Then
       with NewBook_Sub 
      .Title = saArray                                NewBook.Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Aging"                                                NewBook.Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Aging 3m"

      With rngFilter_Ws2        
  .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=saArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
  .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="reporting relevant Location", Operator:=xlFilterValues        '                                                                                                                                   
 .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="<>(a)  0 - 360", Operator:=xlFilterValues

  Set rngCopyAging_Sub = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                         .AutoFilter ' Switch off AutoFilter
      End With                           
  rngCopyAging_Sub.Copy Destination:=NewBook_Sub.Worksheets("Aging ).Cells(1, 1)
```

to be continued

```
With rngFilter_Ws2                    
       .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=saArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
       .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="reporting relevant Location", Operator:=xlFilterValues
      .AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="<>(a)  >= 360 Days", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>(b)  >180 Days and < 360 Days", Operator:=xlFilterValues

         For p = .Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1

            If Future_date > .Cells(p, "U").Value Then  

                .Cells(p, "AH").Replace What:="(c)  <= 180 Days", Replacement:="(c)  <= 90 Days", LookAt:=xlPart,                                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False,                                                          ReplaceFormat:=False    
             Else
         If Future_date < .Cells(p, "U").Value Then    
           .Rows(p).EntireRow.Delete    
          End If
          End If
        Next p    
         Set rngCopyAging_3mEx = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                                .AutoFilter ' Switch off AutoFilter
       End With

    rngCopyAging_3mEx.Copy Destination:=NewBook_Sub.Worksheets("Aging 3m & Expired").Cells(1, 1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
       end if 
       next
      .saveas filename:="KPI" & " " & saArray & " " & ".xlsx"
     end with
     End Sub
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code (on a smaller data set) using debug? This may highlight some issues!

Comment: @ MiguelH I have dont it already but didnt find anything.

Comment: Do you have other function called "Future_date"? Because your Future_date seems to be empty

Comment: @MutjayLee I apologize for that. I have added it in the code please have a look at it.

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense to me. You are using `With rngFilter_Ws2` without defining / initializing the range first. Also, it seems to me that you are trying to use worksheet functions (such as `AutoFilter`) to arrays. Also, why don't you use the variable type `Date` for `current_date` or `Future_date`? Finally, there is a lot of code missing which might contain the missing links (for example the `NewBook_Sub` is missing). You might want to read the following before updating your post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Ralph I have edited the entire code and some pictures to give you clear could you please go through once. Please help me out of this

Comment: @MutjayLee could you please go through my question once.

Comment: I will try my best. But I am having hard time understanding what you are trying to do. As far as I understand, you are trying to organize the DATAS by difference between the date and today. and depends on Column "A" value, you create worksheet with **name= Column"A" & difference between dates** and organize the dates in each corresponding worksheets. Am I getting it correct???

Comment: Not exactly. depends on column A it will create different workbooks for example APE.xlsx,APE_D.xlsx and so on. Difference between dates in column `E` and todays date plus 3months. If it is greater then its replace the text in the column 'G' as `<=90 days`. If it is less then delete the entire row. I hope you have understand it. please help me out

Comment: Writing "<=90 days" and deleting entire row happens on the data workbook? or new created workbook(APE.xlsx,APE_D.xlsx..etc)

Comment: Must happen on new created workbook(APE.xlsx,APE_D.xlsx..etc)

Comment: I still don't have the faintest idea what you are trying to achieve. So, I will leave it to the rest of the community to try and help you. Still, I'd recommend that you improve your post by (1) breaking it down into several post. It seems that this is a compounded question and therefore you have difficulties putting it all into one post. Also, note that this website is not too much about `accounting`, `dunning`, or `aging` but rather about error codes, bugs, code improvements, etc. So, you might want to focus on this and improve upon your current code (which **cannot** work as posted above).

Answer (score 0):

See if this code does what you want and let me know if you have more questions.

```
Sub VBA()
Dim TARGET_WB As Workbook
Dim ORIGINAL_WS, TARGET_WS As Worksheet
```

' Change "ORIGINAL.xlsx" and "SHEET1" to your actual original data workbook and sheet name

```
Set ORIGINAL_WS = Workbooks("ORIGINAL.xlsm").Sheets("SHEET1")

ROW_S = 2
DATA_C = 2
```

' Change "C:\Temp\" to your actual original data path

```
FILE_LOCATION = "C:\Temp\"

With ORIGINAL_WS
    While ROW_E < .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        FILE_NAME = .Cells(ROW_S, 1) & ".xlsx"
        If Dir(FILE_LOCATION & FILE_NAME) = "" Then
            Set TARGET_WB = Workbooks.Add
            TARGET_WB.SaveAs FILE_LOCATIONI & FILE_NAME
            TARGET_WB.Sheets("SHEET1").Rows(1) = .Rows(1).Value
        Else
            WB_ALREADY_OPENED = False
            For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
                If WB.Name = FILE_NAME Then WB_ALREADY_OPENED = True
            Next WB
            If Not (WB_ALREADY_OPENED) Then Workbooks.Open (FILE_LOCATION & FILE_NAME)
            Set TARGET_WB = Workbooks(FILE_NAME)
        End If

        Set TARGET_WS = TARGET_WB.Sheets("SHEET1")

        ROW_E = ROW_S
        While .Cells(ROW_S, 1) = .Cells(ROW_E, 1)
            ROW_E = ROW_E + 1
        Wend
        DATA_LENTH = ROW_E - ROW_S
        TARGET_EOL = TARGET_WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        TARGET_WS.Cells(TARGET_EOL, 1).Resize(DATA_LENTH, 6) = .Cells(ROW_S, 1).Resize(DATA_LENTH, 6).Value


        For i = TARGET_EOL To TARGET_EOL + DATA_LENTH - 1
            With TARGET_WS.Range("G" & i)
```

' I used Select case function for you to edit it easier

```
                If TARGET_WS.Range("E" & i) <> Empty Then
                    Select Case TARGET_WS.Range("E" & i) - DateAdd("M", 3, Date)
                        Case Is < 0: TARGET_WS.Rows(i).Delete: i = i - 1
                        Case 1 To 90: .Value = "<= 90"
                        Case 91 To 180: .Value = "<=180"
                        Case 181 To 270: .Value = "<=270"
                        Case 271 To 360: .Value = "<=360"
                        Case Is >= 361: .Value = ">=360"
                    End Select
                Else
                    If TARGET_WS.Cells(i, 1) <> Empty Then .Value = "SCI No Date"
                End If
            End With
        Next i

        ROW_S = ROW_E
    Wend
End With

For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
    If WB.Name <> ORIGINAL_WS.Parent.Name Then
        WB.Save
        WB.Close
    End If
Next WB


End Sub
```

What this does is

1. Search through column "A" and look for file named after column "A"
2. If there's no file exists, creates workbooks.(Ex. APE.xlsx)
3. If file does exists, checks if they are already opened and if not already opened then open.
4. Doing loop to find data lenth
5. Copy datas to workbook named after column "A"
6. loops through copied data for date and calculate the difference
7. delets entire row (If column "E" date)- (today + 3 month) is less than 0
8. displays the result on column "G" (Ex. <=90)
9. Step 1 to 8 loops until it reach the end of Original Data
10. Save and closes all workbooks except Original Data Workbook

Comment: lee Its throwing error at `TARGET_WS.Cells(TARGET_EOL, 1).Resize(DATA_LENTH, 6) = .Cells(ROW_S, 1).Resize(DATA_LENTH, 6).Value` statement. I think there is something missing in this statement.

Comment: When erro occurs, click debug, then move your mouse over **DATA_LENTH**. It should tell you what DATA_LENTH value is. What is the value?

Comment: DATA_LENTH value is 16068

Comment: Was this error occured after copying some datas? or in the beginning? Did any of the target workbooks created?

Comment: The error were occured i the beginnig . The error is `Object variable or with block varibale not set` .It created the workbook with the name APE.xlsx but for the other it didn't.

Comment: It's really hard to program and trouble shoot without the actual data. Is there anyway you can send me the data via e-mail?

Comment: Could you please drop your mail id. I can send the actual data.

Comment: mutjaylee@gmail.com

Comment: lee please Check your mail